# Convolution of Gaussian with Softmax

Tags: probability, bayesian, integral, softmax

I am trying to integrate the function $f = \int \sigma(\boldsymbol{x})_i \mathcal{N}(x_i | \mu_i, \sigma_i^2) d x_i$ where $\sigma(\boldsymbol{x})_i$ is the softmax function over variables $\boldsymbol{x}$: $\sigma(\boldsymbol{x})_i = \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_j \exp{x_j}}$. I know that exact integral cannot be evaluated analytically, but is there any good approximation that we can approximate $f$ as a Gaussian distribution?

I know that in the two-class case, $\sigma(\boldsymbol{x})$ reduces to logistic sigmoid and it can be approximated by probit function. I am looking for a similar method that can approximate softmax.